# python regular expression percentage sign

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all the parts which contain "~~ account(ed or s) for ~~~~~~~ sale(s)" from the text. And I'm using python!

For example,

```
sentence = "Henry Schenin inc, accounted for approximately 11% of our net sale"
```

my regular expression is

```
rx1 = re.compile('(.|\W){1,100}account(.|\W){1,100}for\W(.|\W){1,200}sale(.|\W){1,200}', re.I)
```

However, this

```
rx1.search(sentence)
```

only returns `None`

and if I use regular expression like

```
rx2 = re.compile('(.|\W){1,100}account(.|\W){1,100}for\W(.|\W){1,200}', re.I)
```

I got,

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 67), match='Henry Schenin inc, accounted for approximately 11>
```

Can anyone help me understand why this regular expression could not catch the part after the percentage sign(%)?

((As I want to extract firms' name listed before "accounted for~~ sale" part I used (.|\W){1,100} at the start of regular expressions.

Comment: `(.|\W){1,100}` is a bad idea as `.` can match what `\W` matches. You must use `re.S` or `re.DOTALL` and just use `.` Why not use just `r'^(.*?)\s*,\s*accounted\s+for\b'` and then `re.search(pattern, sentence)`? Please confirm you need to extract a part of the string from start to the first occurrence of `, accounted for`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew As my texts are not cleared enough, I preferred to use re.I(I have to do some NNP detecting by StanfordTagger after extracting those sentences. thus I don't want to make my text lower cased) Is there any way I can use both of re.I and re.S?  And also, my text are longer than just that example sentence, so I would like to extract the firms' name before "accounted for~~~" which could be one or more than that. In addition, the word "sale" at the end of regular expression is critical, since if a sentence does not contain the word "sale" at the end, it might be not what I wanted

Comment: Yes, using 2 modifiers is as easy as `re.I | re.S`.

Comment: What is your expected output? The same sentence?

Comment: @MichailN yeah right I want to extract the same sentences from my text which is consisted of more than thousands other sentences...! THanks!!

Comment: Then please provide the real life input (you may contract it a bit). And provide the expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh thanks a lot you are a genius!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's an artificial example, but take a look at this.  TEXT =  "Since the consent decree resulting in the divestiture of the AT&T regional operating companies in 1984, the RBOCs have been prevented from manufacturing equipment for use in communications networks. In the Company's fiscal year ended June 30th
2004 ("Fiscal Year 2004"), sales of dental imaging equipment to Henry Schein
Inc., accounted for approximately 11% of the Company's total consolidated sales, luckly." And I want to extract only the last sentence..!

Comment: Please provide some *tangible* requirements for the pattern. Please add the details into the question. I doubt [this](https://regex101.com/r/ToaxKR/1) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
\s+to\s+(.*?account.*? for .*?sale(s){0,1})
```

That will work for your current example.
You need some way to decide where your match begins, in this example I have used to